# Angular $http GET pass authorization

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-status-code-401

Is it possible to pass a user and password to basic auth in AngularJS? I am using a $http to make the request :

```
  var urlsave = myurl;    
  $http({method: 'GET', url: urlsave}).success(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
  })
```

This is the response :

```
Status Code:401 Unauthorized
```

I don't have access to the back end but there is no CORS, i just need to pass it my username and password

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can pass username and password if you know username and password.

for example : `http://username:password@domain.com/api/something`